# How to Extract substrings between two special characters in php or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a *varchar field* in a **MySQL table.**

The field stores different strings i.e. for example

*string1*

*string2*

*string3*

But it stores them in this format:

**+string1+string2+string3+**

i.e. every string is bound by character '+'.

Now I have PHP page coded for accessing this table.

All I require is extracting these string1,string2,string3 in php variables.

I have accessed the database and saved the string "+string1+string2+string3+"
in one php variable.

Now, **Is there any inbuilt function in php (or mysql for that matter), which can give me separated string1, string2, string3 to save in three different php variables?**

Also three strings is just for an example. Various tuples might save different numbers of strings.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You :D

Comment: `$strings = explode('+', $result)`?

Comment: I'd start by looking at explode("+",$str)

Comment: explode() worked like a charm!! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `explode()`. Your code will be like:

```
$strings_arr = explode("+", $mysql_result);
```

So, the Array will contain:

```
$strings_arr[0] = 'string1';
$strings_arr[1] = 'string1';
$strings_arr[2] = 'string1';
```

And so on. This will actually help you: [php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

And if the unexploded string starts with `+`, then you can use a limit in order to remove the first empty value

Comment: Thanks a Lot! It worked like a charm! And i have edited the database entry to just string1+string2. I guess no need for initial start and end `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
$string_arr = explode('+', $strings);
```